# How to: Programmatically add data and table to word document with WordProcessingML Markup

Tags: c#, php, xml, openxml, wordprocessingml

Is it possible to access word document after you modify it's structure through WordProcessingML?
http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php

I have a requirement to add table to a word document not directly with C# but inject xml into C#. The data is coming via List in the below method.
I've to use this data and combine with very large xml markup TO Build the WHOLE TABLE.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZnmb.png)

-create a word document with "hello world" string and save it let say example.docx.

-rename the example.docx to example.zip to convert it to zip file

-extract the zip file and delete the example.zip, once you extract you will see 3 folders(_rels,docProps,word), folder name "word" contain the document.xml file

-modify the document.xml file instead of "Hello World" say "Hello W4rld" and recompress your whole folder to example.zip then change the extention from example.rar to example.docx

open the example.docx giving error. any one have idea?

```
Public static string Method1(List<class> list)
{
//foreachloop
// Build table structure with xml(wordprocessingML)
// Use StringBuilder to append this large xml table structure.

return list.Tostring()
}
```

Comment: why would you recompress with rar? or is that a spelling issue? you definitly have to compress as zip in order to open the file properly. also, what error do you receive opening the docx? is the file readble? does it have any issues in the xml? if its not the rar issue, you likely did more than just replace "Hello World" with "Hello W4rld", eg added a line break etc.

Comment: Sorry my bad,just a spelling issue. It says " We're sorry. We can't open .docx because we found a problem with its contents. If I click details "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"   when I use visual studio I don't see any errors I just replaces a single char

Comment: Create a word file without a table and another one with the word table. Use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to compare both the files. Reflect the code you need and that should give you a good idea how to go about.

Comment: @kkkla I see. Well the error is pretty much saying nothing other than the file is corrupt. I can confirm that just changing text in the xml within a <w:t>Text</w:t> is not an issue. The corruption must take place in another stage of the process that you have described via pseudo code. The logic behind your pseudo code seems fine though, I am doing a similar thing at [wrklst/docxmustache](https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache) and it works fine. as mohammedlok recommends, I would compare both files xml to see what changed.